# Date format changing according to browser

Tags: javascript, date, format

This is my JS function for displaying the date in the browser, but the format is changing according the browser. Means when i open my project on chrome then format is 4/30/2015, and when open on IE then 30 april, 2015. How can i fix this?

```
document.getElementById(lblClock).innerHTML = nd.toLocaleString();
```

I am using this. How can i do this without using Date.js and moment.js? Please help me

Comment: Try using something like moment.js instead

Comment: How can i use this ? using reference in my project or something else?

Comment: That how it behave.  If you want to follow a common format then parse the date and add in.

Comment: How can i do this without using library?

Comment: You do this without library by searching StackOverflow.

Comment: Good idea bro............i dont know Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing Special about this previously i was using this which convert the locale date into a string.

```
document.getElementById(lblClock).innerHTML = nd.toLocaleString();
```

Just give your specific format in which you want to see your date just like this.

```
document.getElementById(lblClock).innerHTML = nd.format('dddd,MMM dd,yyyy,HH:mm:ss');
```

It will work on any browser or any version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use date format lib from http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format
or try to find something similar

Comment: So, maybe i understand your question wrong. What is `nd` in your code `document.getElementById(lblClock).innerHTML = nd.format('dddd,MMM dd,yyyy,HH:mm:ss');` ?